# How to Disable Build Validation when there is a commit to the source branch in the PR

Tags: azure-devops, build, build-pipeline

I have a master branch and which has build validation (2 pipelines, optional and mandatory) branch policy.
I created a PR from my working branch to the master. At this time, 2 pipelines as part of build validation executed. That is ok.
But whenever I commit to the source branch of the above PR (i.e. my working branch), again these pipelines will get executed.

Is there is any way to block this.ie, I don't want to execute the build validation pipelines when I make a commit to the source branch in the PR??